# Huge GeoTIFF file after reprojecting file

Tags: python, geotiff-tiff, rasterio

I have some geotiff file. Their CRS ise EPSG:32635. I want to change crs to EPSG:4326. I use below script from Rasteri doc ([link](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/topics/reproject.html)). In addition I added **'compress': 'lzw'** to compress new geotiff file. But my output file size is huge. For example The size of a 12 MB file is 945 MB after conversion.

How can I solve this problem?

```
import numpy as np
import rasterio
from rasterio.warp import calculate_default_transform, reproject, Resampling

dst_crs = 'EPSG:4326'

with rasterio.open('rasterio/tests/data/RGB.byte.tif') as src:
    transform, width, height = calculate_default_transform(
        src.crs, dst_crs, src.width, src.height, *src.bounds)
    kwargs = src.meta.copy()
    kwargs.update({
        'crs': dst_crs,
        'transform': transform,
        'width': width,
        'height': height,
        'compress': 'lzw'
    })

    with rasterio.open('/tmp/RGB.byte.wgs84.tif', 'w', **kwargs) as dst:
        for i in range(1, src.count + 1):
            reproject(
                source=rasterio.band(src, i),
                destination=rasterio.band(dst, i),
                src_transform=src.transform,
                src_crs=src.crs,
                dst_transform=transform,
                dst_crs=dst_crs,
                resampling=Resampling.nearest)
```

The output 
`{i: dtype for i, dtype in zip(dataset.indexes, dataset.dtypes)}` 
is below.

```
Original img output 
{1: 'uint8', 2: 'uint8', 3: 'uint8'} 
------------- 
Reproject img output 
{1: 'uint8', 2: 'uint8', 3: 'uint8'}
```

**gdalinfo for original image**

`Size is 13691, 16259
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 35N",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",27],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AXIS["Easting",EAST],
    AXIS["Northing",NORTH],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","32635"]]
Origin = (543529.770710000069812,5977099.678410000167787)
Pixel Size = (0.065900000000000,-0.065900000000000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  TIFFTAG_SOFTWARE=pix4dmapper
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=YCbCr JPEG
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
  SOURCE_COLOR_SPACE=YCbCr
ERROR 1: ***/oam_data/aerial_imgs/01.tif: Can not read TIFF directory count
ERROR 1: TIFFReadDirectory:Failed to read directory at offset 15655350
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  543529.771, 5977099.678) ( 27d39'47.28"E, 53d56'25.62"N)
Lower Left  (  543529.771, 5976028.210) ( 27d39'46.73"E, 53d55'50.95"N)
Upper Right (  544432.008, 5977099.678) ( 27d40'36.76"E, 53d56'25.34"N)
Lower Right (  544432.008, 5976028.210) ( 27d40'36.19"E, 53d55'50.67"N)
Center      (  543980.889, 5976563.944) ( 27d40'11.74"E, 53d56' 8.15"N)
Band 1 Block=512x512 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
  NoData Value=-10000
Band 2 Block=512x512 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
  NoData Value=-10000
Band 3 Block=512x512 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
  NoData Value=-10000`

**gdalinfo for reproject image**

`Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: ***/oam_data/aerial_imgs/01_crs_changed.tif
Size is 17689, 12355
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
Origin = (27.662980139607967,53.940449109530391)
Pixel Size = (0.000000785608906,-0.000000785608906)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=LZW
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  27.6629801,  53.9404491) ( 27d39'46.73"E, 53d56'25.62"N)
Lower Left  (  27.6629801,  53.9307429) ( 27d39'46.73"E, 53d55'50.67"N)
Upper Right (  27.6768768,  53.9404491) ( 27d40'36.76"E, 53d56'25.62"N)
Lower Right (  27.6768768,  53.9307429) ( 27d40'36.76"E, 53d55'50.67"N)
Center      (  27.6699285,  53.9355960) ( 27d40'11.74"E, 53d56' 8.15"N)
Band 1 Block=17689x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
Band 2 Block=17689x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
Band 3 Block=17689x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue`

When I try with GDAL using below code the original image is 12 MB and reproject image is 655 MB.

`def gdal_reproject():
    import gdal
    gdal.Warp('***/reproject.tif',
              '***/original.tif', dstSRS='EPSG:4326')`

And this is the output error messages

`ERROR 1: TIFFFetchDirectory:***/aerial_imgs/original.tif: Can not read TIFF directory count
ERROR 1: TIFFReadDirectory:Failed to read directory at offset 15655350
ERROR 1: TIFFFillTile:Read error at row 2048, col 8192, tile 648; got 0 bytes, expected 1664
ERROR 1: TIFFReadEncodedTile() failed.
ERROR 1: ***/original.tif, band 1: IReadBlock failed at X offset 0, Y offset 24: TIFFReadEncodedTile() failed.`

When I use **"compress": "JPEG", photometric": "YCBCR"** parameters instead of **'compress': 'lzw'** the file size has shrunk.The size of original and reproject image almost same.

[image: The basic information of the original and reproject images at QGIS]

Comment: Did you check the 'dtype' value form kwargs?

Comment: What is the dtype of your input dataset?

Comment: Can you check the pixel depth of your output data to see if its the same as the input? It seems to me that the pixel depth went "promoted" to a higher value, to store no_data values outside of the new bounding box after the performing the reprojection.

Comment: What if you make a copy of the output tiff into a new LZW compressed file? Sometimes warping to a compressed tiff is inefficient.

Comment: I can not find pixel depth using Python or QGIS. Do you have any idea @Roger Almengor?

Comment: The result is same @user30184 :(

Comment: ```dataset = rasterio.open('example.tif') ```

Comment: ```{i: dtype for i, dtype in zip(dataset.indexes, dataset.dtypes)} ```

Comment: Please run gdalinfo from the source and target. Pay attention to compression and the image size in pixels.

Comment: That is using rasterio, the last snippet gives the datatype per band.

Comment: And if you do the following for the kwargs parameters?: ``` kwargs.update({
        'crs': dst_crs,
        'transform': transform,
        'width': width,
        'height': height,
        'compress': 'lzw','dtype': 'uint8'
    }

Comment: Thank you @user2856. The problem was solved with your solution. :)

Comment: @fdas I've added as an answer, please accept it.

Answer (score 3):

Your input tif is lossily compressed with JPEG YCBCR which gives much higher compression than lossless LZW.  Try `"compress": "JPEG",  "photometric": "YCBCR"` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
import rasterio
from rasterio.warp import calculate_default_transform, reproject, Resampling

dst_crs = 'EPSG:4326'

with rasterio.open('rasterio/tests/data/RGB.byte.tif') as src:
    transform, width, height = calculate_default_transform(
        src.crs, dst_crs, src.width, src.height, *src.bounds)
    kwargs = src.meta.copy()
    kwargs.update({
        'crs': dst_crs,
        'transform': transform,
        'width': width,
        'height': height,
        'compress': 'lzw',
         'dtype': 'uint8'
    })

    with rasterio.open('/tmp/RGB.byte.wgs84.tif', 'w', **kwargs) as dst:
        for i in range(1, src.count + 1):
            reproject(
                source=rasterio.band(src, i),
                destination=rasterio.band(dst, i),
                src_transform=src.transform,
                src_crs=src.crs,
                dst_transform=transform,
                dst_crs=dst_crs,
                resampling=Resampling.nearest)
```

Sometimes it can happen that when warping a raster dataset to other projection, end up having pixels within the new extent, and they will be assigned to no data to keep the data values. Does that solve your problem? Or do you have the same results?

Comment: The result is same :(

Comment: Could you try testing doing it with gdal?

Comment: gdalwarp -t_srs EPGS: 4326  <input.TIFF>  <output.TIFF>

Comment: Did you have an update on your issue? Did you try an alternative?